# UISwitch Resets when scrolling TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiswitch

I've been searching for this for a long time and haven't got any clear answer.

I have a `UISwitch` as an `accessoryView` in my table view cell.  The problem is that every time I scroll the table, the switch gets reset back to its original state.

Here is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
-(UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    switch1 = [[[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
    [switch1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed :) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [switch1 setOn:YES animated:NO];
    cell.accessoryView = switch1;

    NSString *iconsImage = [[self iconsImages] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    UIImage *cellIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:iconsImage];
    [[cell imageView] setImage:cellIcon];

    CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(65, 18, 150, 25);
    UILabel *iconsNameLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame] autorelease];
    iconsNameLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
    iconsNameLabel.text = [iconsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:iconsNameLabel];

    return cell; 
}
```

By the way, I've declared my switch in the header file and set it as a property and synthesized it.

Comment: Do you mean that each time the switch scrolls **off the screen* and then back on, it turns back on, or does it change even if you scroll just a little bit?

Comment: it changes when the switch scrolls off the screen...

Comment: That's what I thought based on the code.   It is because everytime that it comes on the screen, it is a new switch.

Comment: What do you suggest?...ive tried putting it in the if(cell == nil) but its not working either..im not very used to objective c or iOS...but ive tried alot of different things but no luck..ive read some posts and they suggest that its cz im reusing cells..kindly suggest!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow (SO)! Please accept answers when someone helps you in order to show the correct answer and reward them with added reputation for their help!

Comment: Have a look at my answer: http://goo.gl/5krjHp

Answer (score 1):

So your code as written will add a new button to every cell whenever it is moved onto the screen.  You need to do something very similar to your `iconsImages` and `iconsList` (which I assume are NSArray's).

Here's what you need to do:

1 Add a new `NSMutableArray` to your header file and then properly initialize it in your source file.  This should be almost the same as the two existing array's.  Let's say you call this `iconsSwitchStates`.

2 When you create the switches, set the tag and state like this:

```
[switch1 setTag:indexPath.row];
if ([iconsSwitchStates count] > indexPath.row) {
     [switch1 setOn:[iconsSwitchStates objectAtIndex:[indexPath.row]];
}
```

3 In the function that you already have (`buttonPressed:`) you need to set the state of the switch.

```
[iconsSwitchStates replaceObjectAtIndex:sender.tag withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:sender.on]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Inafziger's answer, I'm using an alternative (slightly different approach for one UISwitch):

You have an `NSMutableArray *swState` and `UISwitch *sw`

in your `cellforRowAtIndexPath:` Method (where you're creating the switch):

```
[sw setOn:[swState count]];
```

And in your sender method:

```
if ([swState count] > 0)
{
     [swState removeObjectAtIndex:0];
}
else
{
     [swState addObject:@"foo"];
}
```